# How to take separate data from LinkedHashMap<String, Double> in Java

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I used `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>` . I want to take separate values from it. If it is `Array` we can use  `.get[2]` ,`.get[5]` etc. for take 2nd and 5th value. But for `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>` how to do it. I used following code. But it print all the values contained in `LinkedHashMap<String, Double>`. I need to take separately.

```
    Set set = mylist.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me1 = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    System.out.print(me1.getKey());
    System.out.println(me1.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `LinkedHashMap#get(Object key)` method

Which will return the value corresponding to the key parameter. Since your keys are `String`, you can not use an `int` to retrieve them.

---

### Example

If your `LinkedHashMap` contains `["key", 2.5]`, calling

```
System.out.println(lnkHashMap.get("key"));
```

will print

```
2.5
```

---

### Addition

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), there is a workaround using a `Stream` object.

```
Double result = hashmap.values()
                       .stream()
                       .skip(2)
                       .findFirst()
                       .get();
```

This will skip the two first values and get to the third one directly and return it.

If not, here is a solution

```
public <T> T getValueByIndex (Map<? extends Object, T> map, int index){
    Iterator<T> it = map.values().iterator();
    T temp = null;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < index ; i++){
        if (it.hasNext()){
            temp = it.next();
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I already used your second part. But for that we need to know extract `"key"` . Yes ,I use `java-8`. I tried your 2nd part. But, `.stream()` gave an error `The method stream() is undefined for the type Collection<Double>`

Comment: @Emalka Are you sure to be using [tag:java-8] ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Sorry my computer SE run time environment is set to `Java 1.8 `   But Eclipse project is set to `Java SE 1.7`. So I tried with 2nd method.But its 1st line gave an error. (sorry ,I have less experience in java) `Syntax error on token "public", Type expected after this token`   and   `Syntax error on token "getValueByIndex", = expected`  and   `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`  .

Comment: @Emalka Change Eclipse to Java 1.8

Answer (score 1):

It could be the case that you are using the wrong data structure for your purpose.

If you look closely to the [LinkedHashMap API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) you will notice that it is indeed a Map and the only way to access a previously stored value is by providing its key.

But if you really think you need to access the i*th* value of the LinkedHashMap according to its insertion-order (or access-order) you can use a simple utility method like the following:

### Java 8 Solution

```
private static <K, V> Optional<V> getByInsertionOrder(LinkedHashMap<K, V> linkedHashMap, int index) {
    return linkedHashMap.values().stream()
        .skip(index)
        .findFirst();
}
```

### Java 7 Soution

```
private static <K, V> V getByInsertionOrder(LinkedHashMap<K, V> linkedHashMap, int index) {

    if (index < 0 || index >= linkedHashMap.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator = linkedHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        iterator.next();
    }

    return iterator.next().getValue();
}
```